# An Einstein summation question

Tags: tensors

Let $\eta_{ab}$ be the Minkowski metric and $T_{ab}=T_{[ab]}+T_{(ab)}$, where $T_{(ab)}=\frac{1}{2}(T_{ab}+T_{ba})$ and $T_{[ab]}=\frac{1}{2}(T_{ab}-T_{ba})$. Is it true that $\eta_{ab}T_{ab}=\eta_{ab}T_{(ab)}$, assuming $a,b$ range over the same integer values? I think so, since assuming the latter, $\eta_{ab}T_{ab}=\eta_{ab}T_{ba}$, so $\eta_{ab}T_{(ab)}=\eta_{ab}\frac{1}{2}(T_{ab}+T_{ba})=\frac{1}{2}\eta_{ab}T_{ab}+\frac{1}{2}\eta_{ab}T_{ba}=\frac{1}{2}\eta_{ab}T_{ab}+\frac{1}{2}\eta_{ab}T_{ab}=\eta_{ab}T_{ab}$. Is this correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Expand the sum using that $\eta_{ab}\neq 0$ if and only if $a=b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because $\eta_{ab}=\eta_{ba}\implies\eta_{ab}T_{ba}=\eta_{ba}T_{ba}=\eta_{ab}T_{ab}$, where the last $=$ relabels indices.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$η_{ab}T_{ab}=η_{ab}\left(T_{[ab]}+T_{(ab)}\right)$$
$$=η_{ab}T_{[ab]}+η_{ab}T_{(ab)}$$
$$=0+η_{ab}T_{(ab)}$$
$$=η_{ab}T_{(ab)}$$

because the inner product of a symmetric and an antisymmetric tensor is zero.